# What is the cni0 interface seen on ifconfig

Tags: networking, interface

What does the cni0 interface denote?

```
 cni0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:F1:80:00:00 
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
         RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
         RX bytes:60 (60.0 B) 
         TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Reference:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/toh/netgear.cg3200

Regards

Ed

Comment: OpenWRT is not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Edward Collins...  I am duckduckgoing right now for a clear answer for this question. cni0 is the device related to bridge interface in many unix flavors. Its name PROBABLY stands for Computer Network Interfaces.